# A man who can move things with his eyes

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've been searching for a long time for a movie about a man who can move things with this eyes who I think is battling with his more evil sister who has the same power. I believe it was a made for TV. Movie released in the late 90s or early 2000s.

Here are the scenes I remember:

1. The man is at a party in a high rise building where is talked into "pushing" a friend across the floor, then he is slapped on the back by someone causing his head to move up and down throwing his friend out of the high rise window.
2. The man is caught by his sister (she may not be related) or bad woman and tied to a chair with a device designed to keep his eyes open while a laser shines in his eyes to blind him.
3. The evil woman is sitting near a bird in a cage waiting for someone, the bird is annoying her and she stares at it long enough to boil the birds blood causing it to explode.
4. The evil woman is in a sauna or near a hot tub and is controlling another man making him walk into the hot tub downing himself.

Hope someone out there can help identify this movie.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

[Scanners III: The Takeover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanners_III:_The_Takeover)

> Helena Monet (Liliana Komorowska), a Scanner is troubled by the
>   painful side-effects of her telepathic powers. This drives her to try
>   her adoptive father's untested, experimental drug called Eph-3
>   (pronounced "F3"), a variant of the drug Ephemerol prescribed to
>   Scanners to help attenuate the myriad voices (representing the
>   thoughts of people around them) which their natural, inborn telepathy
>   otherwise forces them to hear. Her use of Eph-3 causes her to lose her
>   sense of moral conscience, making her into a megalomaniac. She kills
>   her father (Colin Fox) and takes over his pharmaceutical company. Her
>   long-lost adopted brother Alex, also a Scanner, is alerted to her
>   dangerous behavior and attempts to stop her.
>
> As her rise to power and desire for global dominance gains momentum,
>   her brother must fend off the attackers whom she has sent after him
>   and ultimately defeat his sister to save the world.

Bird scene 16:06

Tub scene 34:51

Comment: yes! that is it! I cant thank you enough for your help!!